# PKI.js working with an imported browser certificate

Tags: javascript, encryption

I created a certificate using this example at https://pkijs.org/examples/CMSEnvelopedExample.html

I saved the generated certificate into a .cer file and imported into Browser. (PKCS #1 SHA-1 with RSA)
This example uses the generated certificate to encrypt and decrypt messages. (always with a new generated certificate)

How can I modify this example to work with imported certificate (into the browser) and not the generated certificate?
I have to work with the imported certificate and not with a new generated certificate.

Thanks.

Comment: You could store the certificate into browser localStorage instead of importing into browser keystore.